# Can not catch HttpMethod: OPTIONS on a http request

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core, .net-core, actionfilterattribute

I'm writing an ActionFilterAttribute where I check userId route/query parameters and compare it against the subject of a jwt token. I noticed that my Action Filter gets triggered twice. In chrome I can see that an OPTIONS request is sent to the server and in my debug console output I can see the call with the correct http method:

```
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost:Information: Request starting HTTP/1.1 OPTIONS http://localhost:5000/api/v1/users/33417
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost:Information: Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://localhost:5000/api/v1/users/33417 application/json
```

But when it hits my Action Filter, Http Method is always set as GET so I can not make my filter return on an OPTIONS call.

Here is a basic OnActionExecutionAsync override method:

```
    public override Task OnActionExecutionAsync(ActionExecutingContext context, ActionExecutionDelegate next)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("URL CALL: " + context.HttpContext.Request.GetDisplayUrl());
        Debug.WriteLine("HTTP METHOD: " + context.HttpContext.Request.Method);
        if (HttpMethods.IsOptions(context.HttpContext.Request.Method))
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("HTTP METHOD: OPTIONS");
            return base.OnActionExecutionAsync(context, next);
        }
        // Other Code ....
    }
```

The debug log:

```
URL CALL: http://localhost:5000/api/v1/users/33417
HTTP METHOD: GET 
URL CALL: http://localhost:5000/api/v1/users/33417 
HTTP METHOD: GET
```

Another interesting point is that if I request OPTIONS from Postman tool my API returns this error message:

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "UnsupportedApiVersion",
        "message": "The HTTP resource that matches the request URI 'http://localhost:5000/api/v1/users/33417' with API version '1' does not support HTTP method 'OPTIONS'.",
        "innerError": null
    }
}
```

Here is my Cors Configuration in Startup:

```
services.AddCors(options => options.AddPolicy(_constants.CorsPolicy,
                builder => builder.AllowAnyOrigin()
                    .AllowAnyMethod()
                    .AllowAnyHeader()
                    .AllowCredentials()
                    .Build()));
```

Is there any way I can catch the OPTIONS http method in my Action Filter?

Comment: Do you have CORS configured on the project?

Comment: Yes, it is configured to `AllowAnyMethod()`

Comment: Then that's the answer, the CORS middleware is handling the OPTIONS request, and what your filter sees is the GET request that follows the OPTIONS request.

Answer (score 1):

Since you have CORS setup on the app,
it responds to the OPTIONS pre-flight request before MVC.
That request never gets to MVC, so your filter cannot see it.
What your filter sees is the GET request that comes after the OPTIONS request.

```
app.UseCors(); //Sees OPTIONS request, sets response and returns

app.UseMvc();
```

Comment: Ok I understand this but there is a different situation, in my debug log I can see 2 incoming requests:
`Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost:Information: Request starting HTTP/1.1 OPTIONS http://localhost:5000/api/v1/users/33417
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost:Information: Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://localhost:5000/api/v1/users/33417 application/json `
I put a debug log on the action filter and the action filter triggers twice both with GET Http method. Looks like the OPTIONS method gets converted to GET method.

Comment: Can you check the URL on both of them in the action filter?

Comment: I put a debug log:

`URL CALL: http://localhost:5000/api/v1/users/33417
HTTP METHOD: GET
URL CALL: http://localhost:5000/api/v1/users/33417
HTTP METHOD: GET`
Same URL's are called

Comment: That's pretty odd then. Be sure to add those things to your question.